# Display HTTP headers using Open::URI?

Tags: ruby, curl, open-uri

with Open::URI, I can do the following:

```
require 'open-uri'
#check status
open('http://google.com').status
#get entire html
open('http://google.com').read
```

Is it possible to get the HTTP headers of a request so things can be debugged, something like Curls' `curl -I http://google.com`?

```
$ curl -I google.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 17 Dec 2012 14:28:17 GMT
Expires: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 14:28:17 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the `meta` method of the virtual filehandle:

```
open('http://google.com'){|f| pp f.meta  }
{"x-frame-options"=>"SAMEORIGIN",
 "expires"=>"-1",
 "p3p"=>
  "CP=\"This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info.\"",
 "content-type"=>"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",
 "date"=>"Mon, 17 Dec 2012 14:37:29 GMT",
 "server"=>"gws",
 "x-xss-protection"=>"1; mode=block",
 "set-cookie"=>
  "PREF=ID=d2fb8a93d369bcd2:FF=0:TM=1355755049:LM=1355755049:S=ONVSP6n2jtluFgll; expires=Wed, 17-Dec-2014 14:37:29 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com, NID=67=OFEvvHCOa3C6wScQCUIKfu_89oL9MSmnFjwN-u5LX_foP8NLsX7G9dq48NLVrf4WUXhqOA1jb38s0e9qeRp1Iwx_LT_N8IuF0Qi6dXVtR2zdvA86INqtfg5uNrKvxJfJ; expires=Tue, 18-Jun-2013 14:37:29 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly",
 "cache-control"=>"private, max-age=0",
 "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked"}
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/Meta.html