# How do I only read the header for a URL in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-headers

How do I read the header only in Ruby? I tried some of the options in the documentation for `open` but it still reads the entire file.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html#method-i-open

```
irb(main):153:0> html=open(url, :content_length_proc => lambda {|len| p len  })
177602
=> #<Tempfile:C:/Users/Chloe/AppData/Local/Temp/open-uri20140220-8496-o5zlda>
```

I want something like `curl -I` or `wget --spider`.

---

Ok found two ways!

`open(url){|f| f.meta['content-length']}`

`Net::HTTP.start(uri.host) {|http| http.head(uri.path)['content-length']}`

I like the first as it's simpler and doesn't require creating then parsing a URI object.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900207/getting-headers-from-a-ruby-nethttp-request-before-making-the-request

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454956/get-http-headers-before-downloading-with-open-uri-ruby

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar That question is to get the REQUEST headers, not the RESPONSE headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware this isn't possible with OpenURI but is with Net:HTTP (this may have changed).  See this answer:

[Get HTTP Headers before downloading with open-uri (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454956/get-http-headers-before-downloading-with-open-uri-ruby)

which suggests you use `Net::HTTP`'s `request_get` method.

Comment: If you're just going to link to another answer, I recommend that you make a comment, not an answer.

Comment: well i can copy the text of that answer but it seems pointless

Comment: I agree. Which is why I made a comment and voted to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to trying a gem, [httpclient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient) is great for that:

```
require 'httpclient'
HTTPClient.new.head('http://google.com')
```

Comment: I think the solution you suggested would execute a HEAD request and not retrieve the headers of the request. To retrieve the header with httpclient, you should do something like `HTTPClient.new.get('http://google.com').headers`. However, this would require to read the all response.